# MacBook screen is black, everything else works

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My MacBook Pro 2018 (with Monterey) screen is not working (it’s black), but everything else works (I can use an external monitor).

What could be the reason and can it be fixed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Usually the first simple steps to take would be an SMC (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295) and PRAM Reset (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063), as well as seeing if the issue is already present on the boot screen (press the power button, then press and hold alt/option).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll try it all! In the meantime, I am urgently making a backup of my data just in case, I had to spend quite a lot of time restarting it and logging in using voiceover.

Comment: which model is the MacBook? Which version of MacOS?

Comment: @slartibartfast MacBook Pro 2018, Monterey. Could it be that it was updated overnight and the new OS version (Monterey) caused the problem?

Comment: First: you checked wether you can [increase the brightness via the touch bar](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2704/mac)?

Comment: Regarding yor question about wether the update causes this: I do not know, sorry. I assume your MBP is now on MacOS 12.5, isn’t it?

Comment: @slartibartfast I tried increasing brightness, yes, it does not help.

Comment: @slartibartfast 12.4

Comment: You can check wether repairing your startup disk helps: You need to do this job via macOS Recovery.
1. Make sure your Mac is shut down completely.
2. Press the Power button while you press and hold the *Command and R* keys.
3. When you see the Apple logo, you can release the keys.
4. Type your password if you set one for your Mac. 
5. You will see the MacOS Utilities  interface. Then, you need to click *Disk Utility* and open it. 6. Select the startup disk and then click *First Aid*. 
7. Click *Run*.
8. When the process ends, click *Done* to close the interface.

Comment: @slartibartfast Will it work with an external monitor? I was only able to see anything on my external monitor after I logged in using voiceover.

Comment: You get a boot screen on the internal display when you restart?

Comment: press *Command–Brightness Down* to turn video mirroring on or off when your Mac is connected to a secondary display. However, the dim brightness button isn’t displayed by default on the touch bar, so you have to touch the *<* button first to expand the “control strip” in order to see it.

Comment: @slartibartfast No boot screen, the screen is always black.

Comment: @slartibartfast Thanks for the tip, I will try it